# Is it possible to provide a hover functionality over bubble chart using VBA in Powerpoint?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, powerpoint

I am exploring the powerpoint world for a project. Just need to know whether i can customise a bubble chart in Power point. I need to provide hover element for individual data points and also color the data points according to some range values.

Please provide me with some resources to start with if possible.

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28049828/PowerPoint-2010-programming-charts-with-VBA.html

http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2010/12/better-chart-tooltips-with-microsoft-excel-2010.html
Above are few of  the resources i have gone through.

Thanks in Advance.[image]

Comment: http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/vba_pop.html

Comment: myShape.ActionSettings(ppMouseOver).SoundEffect.Name = "applause"